# id for nested documents in array in nest.js with mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

Is there a way to create each document inside an array with an auto-generated _id?

I am trying with this models:

```js
// Nested Document
export class Group extends Document {
  @Prop({ required: true, unique: true, auto: true, })
  _id?: Types.ObjectId;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  count?: number;
  ...
}

// Main Document
@Schema()
export class Party extends Document {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  direction: string;

  @Prop({ type: Array<Group>, required: true, _id: true })
  groups: Array<Group>;
  ...
}

export const PartySchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Party);
```

But in my PartyService, when I create an party, nested _id's aren't being created. For example, if I run this:

```js
create(){
  return await this.model.create({
    direction: "Main st.",
    groups: [
      {
        count: 5
      },
      {
        count: 7
      }
    ]
  });
}
```

It just create an document as next:

```json
{
  _id: "a3d768f1..."
  direction: "Main st.",
  groups: [
    {
      count: 5
    },
    {
      count: 7
    }
  ],
  createdAt: ...,
  updatedAt: ...,
  ...,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mongoose, when you define a nested document inside an array using a schema, the subdocument's _id field is not automatically generated. This is because the subdocument is considered embedded, and Mongoose doesn't generate _id for embedded documents by default.

In order to mitigate this challenge, you need to manually generate and assign the `_id` before saving the party document.

```js
@Injectable()
export class PartyService {
  constructor(@InjectModel(Party.name) private model: Model<Party>) {}

  async create(dir, groups) {
    const party = new this.model({
      direction: dir,
      groups: groups
    });

    // Generate and assign _id for each group
    party.groups.forEach((group) => {
      group._id = Types.ObjectId();
    });

    return await party.save();
  }
}
```

An example of groups value as paramater to PartyService.create() could be:

```js
const groups = [
  {
    count: 1,
  },
  {
    count: 2,
  },
],
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm trying to avoid doing it manually in code. If no other solution works, I'll try it then.

Comment: Well, then [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-autopopulate) is definitely the answer.

Comment: I couldn't afford to lose any more time on the problem, so I skipped it, avoiding access to each nested object. However, now I need it, which is why I decided to create a schema in the database and remove the array from the parent. In the end, I believe that what you suggested is the only way to handle nested objects with ids without using extern dependencies. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might have forgotten to add this in the nested document part, also you dont have to extend from Document. So `extends Document` can be skipped

The code will look like this

```
@Schema({ _id: true })
export class Group {
  @Prop({ required: true, unique: true, auto: true, })
  _id?: Types.ObjectId;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  count?: number;
  ...
}
```

If you dont want the `__v`, `timestamps`, skipp those as well, like following

```
{_id: true, timestamps: false, versionKey: false}
```

Comment: I thought it would work, but it doesn't :c. In the example I simplified the way I'm saving the document, it's actually an object of a class that only has the fields to save, not the _id field etc. Could it be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
export const ObjectIdType = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;
@Prop({ required: false, type: ObjectIdType })
_id: string;
```

please try this code

Comment: It doesn't look like what I'm trying to do, anyway I want the _id to be of type Types.ObjectId.

Comment: export const ObjectIdType = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;
@Prop({ required: false, type: ObjectIdType })
_id: ObjectIdType;

Comment: The above code can solve your problem

Comment: No, because it's a const, but in your fix you're using it as a type, which gives an error.

Comment: I've tried it without saving the type to a const, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, it's my problem. Here is the complete code

  ```` export type ObjectId = typeof mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;
  export const ObjectIdType = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;
  @Prop({ required: false, type: ObjectIdType })
  _id: ObjectId; ````